# Laravel not add foreign key in PostgreSQL

Tags: laravel, postgresql, foreign-keys, migration

I try to migrate two tables in Laravel
DB: **PostgreSQL**

```
Schema::create('paises', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigincrements('id');
    $table->string('descripcion', 50);
    $table->string('abreviatura',3)->nullable();
    $table->string('genticilio',60)->nullable();
    $table->string('usuario_creacion', 20);
    $table->dateTime('fecha_creacion');
    $table->string('usuario_modificacion',20)->nullable();
    $table->dateTime('fecha_modificacion')->nullable();
});


Schema::create('provincias_departamentos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigincrements('id');
    $table->string('descripcion', 50);
    $table->string('abreviatura',3)->nullable();
    $table->string('genticilio',60)->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_pais');
    $table->foreign('id_pais')->references('id')->on('paises');
    $table->string('usuario_creacion', 20);
    $table->dateTime('fecha_creacion');
    $table->string('usuario_modificacion',20)->nullable();
    $table->dateTime('fecha_modificacion')->nullable();
});
```

I do not have errors when making the migrations, but when verifying the keys for a base in the database, they are not found.
Log in at the time of migrations:

```
Migrating: 2019_01_01_000001_crear_tabla_paises
Migrated:  2019_01_01_000001_crear_tabla_paises
Migrating: 2019_01_01_000002_crear_tabla_provincias_depatarmentos
Migrated:  2019_01_01_000002_crear_tabla_provincias_depatarmentos
```

Comment: Hi @Fed3x, it would be helpful if you included the errors you are encountering. It isn't quite clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**English:**

The error is mine, I used a SQL client that did not allow me to see the foreign keys.
Use pgAdmin v4 and the foreign keys appeared correctly

**Spanish:**

El error es mio, usaba un cliente SQL que no me permitio ver las claves foraneas.
Use el pgAdmin v4 y me aparecieron correctamente las claves foraneas